# I can't display parameter value in report header in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm developing a small application in c# and I'm using Crystal Reports for reporting. I want to display parameter values in report header but I can't. How can i display parameter values in report header?

```
            ClassParams.EMANET_KITAP_ID = txtKitapID.Text;
            ParameterFields From = new ParameterFields();
            ParameterField KID = new ParameterField();
            KID.Name = "EMANET_KITAP_ID";
            ParameterDiscreteValue val = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            val.Value = ClassParams.EMANET_KITAP_ID;
            KID.CurrentValues.Add(val);
            From.Add(KID);
            crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = From;


class ClassParams
{
    public static string KID;
    public static string EMANET_KITAP_ID
    {
        get { return KID; }
        set { KID = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think more information is needed to help you.  I'm using Crystal Reports 2016 (not Visual Studio), and I am able to create a Parameter Field, drop it into the Report Header section and then preview the report and it displays as expected.  You may want to update this question to include details on your environment such as the version of crystal reports or visual studio you are using.  Include any C# code that is used to populate the parameter field as well.

Comment: I'm using Crystal Reports 2011

Comment: ClassParams.EMANET_KITAP_ID = txtKitapID.Text;
                ParameterFields From = new ParameterFields();
                ParameterField KID = new ParameterField();
                KID.Name = "EMANET_KITAP_ID";
                ParameterDiscreteValue val = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
                val.Value = ClassParams.EMANET_KITAP_ID;
                KID.CurrentValues.Add(val);
                From.Add(KID);
                crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = From;

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have a multi-value parameter.
Since such a parameter stores the values as an array, you need to "flatten" the array.
If it's a String parameter, you can simply create a formula like this:

```
Join({?yourStringParameter}, ', ' );
```

If the data type is not string, loop through the array and concatenate the values to a string variable.